# ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have a requirement to compress, convert and generate thumnails from video uploads.

The live server is Linux but for development we are using Windows 7 PC's both using PHP 5.4.

It seems that ffmpeg is different to ffmpeg-php with ffmpeg-php only being able to generate the thumbnails.

Is there any way to use ffmpeg as a php extension on windows and/or linux?

Is there a compiled dll of ffmpeg-php that is compatible with php 5.4?

Is there a php alternative to ffmpeg for the purpose of the above requirements that will work on **Linux** and windows?

Thanks

Asa

Comment: Personally Id reccommend to the client that they use a third party encoding service (like [ZenCoder](http://zencoder.com/)) which you could then integrate with from the application.

Comment: It's a little awkward but you could call the ffmpeg commands using 'system()'.

Comment: I already find different versions of ffmpeg on Linux difficult to code against (ever-changing API). Adding the seemingly not-so-actively maintained ffmpeg-php extension never looked like a solution to me. Certainly not an easy way to get it to work cross-platform. I'd second @prodigitalson: If you can afford it at all, use an external service. I've sucessfully worked with [Transloadit](http://transloadit.com/).

Comment: ffmpeg-php is not a FFmpeg project. There is also [FFmpegPHP](https://github.com/char0n/ffmpeg-php) which is a pure OO PHP port of ffmpeg-php and is less out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP-FFmpeg or php_ffmpeg.dll is only good for generating thumbnails and querying the properties of a video file. See http://x32.elijst.nl/fftest.php54 for the functions within my php_ffmpeg.dll for PHP 5.4. API reference: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/

For video compression on a webserver, you'll have to do system calls to ffmpeg with exec or popen. Some words on this can be found here:
http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts

Late edit: I build php_ffmpeg.dll for all kinds op Windows PHP flavors. See this forum on Apachelounge: http://www.apachelounge.com/viewforum.php?f=6

Another late edit: there is a second PHP extension which uses FFMpeg now:
https://github.com/chung-leong/av/wiki by the maker of http://www.php-qb.net/
I have added php_av.dll to my builds. See the Apachelounge forum: http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=27023#27023

Answer (score 0):

This will work better .

shell_exec('ffmpeg -i C:\xampp\htdocs\videoCutting\movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 -async 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\videoCutting\SampleVideoNew.mp4')